# geth - error when starting the first node - ubuntu

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, ubuntu

I try to do the steps from here:
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/getting-started/private-net
I run the first commnad:

```
geth --datadir="/tmp/eth/60/01" -verbosity 6 --ipcdisable --port 30301 --http.port 8101 console 2>> /tmp/eth/60/01.log
```

I get this error: "bash: /tmp/eth/60/01.log: No such file or directory"

Comment: I created /tmp/eth/60, is that what I should do?

Comment: Does the `/tmp/eth/60/01.log` exist? If it exists perhaps there is a problem with the permissions, if it doesn't exists you could create it with `touch /tmp/eth/60/01.log`.